# How to make code inside a for loop wait between each iteration after the first one?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to make JavaScript wait some amount of time to iterate through an array after the first time it's done it.

```js
let ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
let canvasWidth = window.innerWidth;
let canvasHeight = window.innerHeight;


let snake = [[100, 100], [100, 100], [100, 100]];
let snakeThickness = 30;
let snakeDirection = "Down";

function drawSnake() {
  for (let i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
    ctx.fillRect(snake[i][0], snake[i][1], snakeThickness, snakeThickness);
  }
}

drawSnake();

function moveSnake() {
    setInterval(function () {
      if (snakeDirection === "Down") {
        for (let i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
          ctx.clearRect(snake[i][0], snake[i][1], snakeThickness, snakeThickness);
          snake[i][1] += 30;
          drawSnake();
        }
      }
    }, 150)
}
  
moveSnake();
```

```css
canvas {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="900" height="500">

  </canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: You want to wait after each individual iteration, or you want to wait after the first time the loop finishes?

Comment: it seems like you have to look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Answer (score 0):

Using async and await, you can do this:

```
const sleep = (milliseconds) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds))
}
```

```
const list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
const doSomething = async () => {
  for (const item of list) {
    await sleep(1000)
    console.log('')    
  }
}

doSomething()
```

You can change the for loop to your needs. This is just an example

So in your case:

```
for (let i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
await sleep(milliseconds);
    ctx.fillRect(snake[i][0], snake[i][1], snakeThickness, snakeThickness);
  }
```